# Ember.js working with single member of child enumerable

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to set a property on an input bound to a model, but I don't know how to get to this single element. Here is my controller action:

```
acceptEdit: function(item) {
  items = this.get('items')
  items.toArray().forEach(function(item){
    item.set('isEditing', false);
  });
  items.save();
}
```

The Items belong to a Category. Here is the Category model:

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  items: DS.hasMany('item'),
  itemCount: function() {
    return this.get('items.length');
  }.property('items.@each')
});
```

So, when acceptEdit is called I can get all the items for the category for the current route, but I can't figure out how to get at the exact item being edited. Thus, my inelegant code that just loops over all items to set 'isEditing' to false. Clobbering works, but isn't ideal :\

Is there a way I can get the individual item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really only have two options: search through the array, or store the one that is currently being edited. If you don't want to store the one being edited, just use the [findBy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_findBy) method to get the object that is being edited.

```
var items = this.get('items');
var editingItem = items.findBy('isEditing', true);
// I use tryInvoke in case one isn't found. That might not be possible for you.
Ember.tryInvoke(editingItem, 'set', ['isEditing', false]);
```

Comment: I've marked it as a solution, but I feel motivated to ask. Is this any more efficient than just clobbering? The reason I say that is because for the purposes of this app, I am okay with having all the items 'isEditing' property set to false.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit more efficient. By changing all of them you fire every observer for every element of the array. By changing only one, you're only firing one set of observers. Depending on how you're using the items, that could make a huge difference or none at all.

Comment: Great explanation. I hadn't thought about it that way.